# Open and Select Item in Windows Explorer (Unicode) - Python

Tags: python, unicode, windows-explorer

I know how to open and select file in windows explorer by using explorer.exe commandline options '/n,@/select ' but I can only make it work with regular characters. Anyone have idea how to make it support unicode characters such as this 五輪代? I've tried to encode it with 'utf-8' but it didn't work, I'm sure there's a proper way to do it I just don't know how I hope someone can give me idea. Thanks in advance! :)

here's my sample code:

```
import win32api

win32api.ShellExecute(None, 'open', 'explorer.exe',
                      '/n,@/select, ' + file_path, None, 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ctypes` to access the API in a more direct way: (file_path should be a Python unicode object, not utf-8)

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u'open', u'explorer.exe', 
                                    u'/n,/select, ' + file_path, None, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode#FUNBEGINS) may be of some use. It's for using unicode filenames with python. But it doesn't mention anything about pyWin32.

Comment: Yup I read about this before, got Idea about unicodes but no clue on how to use it in selecting items in windows explorer. I need to know how to pass unicode (utf-8) paths to explorer.exe commandline args, whether it's possible or I have to find other ways of selecting items in windows explorer that supports unicode.

Comment: URL appears to be dead